# Convert word xml to html and html to word xml(Using Java)

Tags: java, xml, ms-word, xsd, jtidy

I tried some ways(**Jtidy**) to Convert word XML to HTML and HTML to word XML through JAVA. But missing some word properties in Final word XML file.

Note: We have worked XML tags based on a schema.

Is there a better way to convert Word XML to HTML? (vice-versa) Or is there a better alternative to using a word with our XML schema?

Answer (score 0):

docx4j can do docx to html; docx4j-ImportXHTML can convert XHTML to docx.

How your XML schema can be leveraged depends a bit on whether it is text or data oriented.